# Out of gas in subcontract

Tags: out-of-gas

If I send ether from contractB to contractA, then get error "out of gas".

Increase the amount of gas does not help.

In "VM Trace Transaction" 
http://testnet.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x24269877942122ea5e022833e2dbd80f543458be2195ad2df222387cff7f5382
I see, then call "contractA.send(msg.value);" don't send gas to subcontract.

How to make these contracts work?

```
contract contractA {
    function() {
        for(uint i = 0;i<10; ++i)
            msg.sender.send(msg.value/10);
    }
}

contract contractB
{
    address contractA = 0x2EA16ad451ca2aA32E06f476691D1529cF11BaC7; // TestNet!!!
    function() {
        if (msg.sender != contractA) {
            contractA.send(msg.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add gas to the transaction by calling `msg.sender.call.gas(10000).value(msg.value/10)()`.

*Be Careful:* this could be vulnerable to recursive call attacks. In your case it isn't, but just be aware when sending gas to unknown contracts.

Comment: Where can I read the documentation for this command?   Maybe contractA.call.gas(10000).value(msg.value)?

Comment: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#address

Comment: And yes, for the call to `contractA` that would be correct, except you're missing the parentheses at the end.

Comment: call returns a boolean :)